# What should I do if I have seven segment pins in different ports?

Tags: mplab, xc8, seven-segment-display

In my circuit, 7 segment pins is in different port like:Seg A to SegD (in RA0 to RA4) SegE(in RF1) SegF (RG4) SegG(RG3). I can count 0 to 9 with setting bits one by one. I need to count 0-9999 but ı can't store values. How can ı do that for my specs?

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#define DISP1 RD7
#define DISP2 RD6
#define DISP3 RD5
#define DISP4 RD4
#define SEGA  RA0
#define SEGB  RA1
#define SEGC  RA2
#define SEGD  RA3
#define SEGE  RF1
#define SEGF  RG4
#define SEGG  RG3
void main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();



  TRISD = 0x00; // Set All Pins To Be Output Pins
  PORTD = 0x00; // Initially Clear All The 8-Pins
  while(1)
  {
       SEGA=1;SEGB=1;SEGC=1;SEGD=1;SEGE=1;SEGF=1;SEGG=0;DISP4=1;//0
      __delay_ms(500);

          SEGA=0;SEGB=1;SEGC=1;SEGD=0;SEGE=0;SEGF=0;SEGG=0;DISP4=1;//1
      __delay_ms(500);

          SEGA=1;SEGB=1;SEGC=0;SEGD=1;SEGE=1;SEGF=0;SEGG=1;DISP4=1;//2
      __delay_ms(500);

      SEGA=1;SEGB=1;SEGC=1;SEGD=1;SEGE=0;SEGF=0;SEGG=1;DISP4=1;//3
      __delay_ms(500);

      SEGA=0;SEGB=1;SEGC=1;SEGD=0;SEGE=0;SEGF=1;SEGG=1;DISP4=1;//4
      __delay_ms(500);

      SEGA=1;SEGB=0;SEGC=1;SEGD=1;SEGE=0;SEGF=1;SEGG=1;DISP4=1;//5
      __delay_ms(500);

      SEGA=1;SEGB=0;SEGC=1;SEGD=1;SEGE=1;SEGF=1;SEGG=1;DISP4=1;//6
      __delay_ms(500);

      SEGA=1;SEGB=1;SEGC=1;SEGD=0;SEGE=0;SEGF=0;SEGG=0;DISP4=1;//7
      __delay_ms(500);
     SEGA=1;SEGB=1;SEGC=1;SEGD=1;SEGE=1;SEGF=1;SEGG=1;DISP4=1;//8
      __delay_ms(500);

      SEGA=1;SEGB=1;SEGC=1;SEGD=1;SEGE=0;SEGF=1;SEGG=1;DISP4=1;//9
      __delay_ms(500);


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

If you want 4 digits, you had to multiplex your display.

Write a table where you define each number:

```
const uint8_t LEDTable[10] = {0b00111111,   //led drive for 0
                              0b00000110,   //led drive for 1
                              ....
                              0b01101101};   //led drive for 9
```

Do the multiplexing in an interrupt routine.
In the interrupt you had to do the output for each digit:
ones
tens
hunderts...

The output for each digit could look like:

```
SEGA = (value & 0x01) ? 1:0;
SEGB = (value & 0x02) ? 1:0;
SEGC = (value & 0x04) ? 1:0;
SEGD = ...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer  mike that helped to me a lot .